# Pivoting in Vertica

Tags: sql, t-sql, vertica

I have a table like below:

```
Geography        Period        Campaign        VariableName        VariableValue
11111            4/1/2017      ABC             TV_Imp              0.4
11111            4/2/2017      ABC             TV_Imp              0.5
11112            4/1/2017      ABC             TV_Imp              0.1
11113            4/2/2017      ABC             TV_Clicks           0.7
11113            4/2/2017      CDE             TV_Clicks           0.7
11113            4/3/2017      FGH             TV_Imp              0.5
```

I'd like to transform/pivot that table to:

```
Geography    Period    ABC_TV_Imp    ABC_TV_Clicks    CDE_TV_Clicks    FGH_TV_Imp
11111        4/1/2017  0.4           0                0                0
11111        4/2/2017  0.5           0                0                0
11112        4/1/2017  0.1           0                0                0
11113        4/2/2017  0             0.7              0                0
11113        4/2/2017  0             0                0.7              0
11113        4/3/2017  0             0                0                0.5
```

The problem here is that I do not know ahead of time what values under `Campaign` and `VariableName` columns are going to be. They could range from ~100-400 distinct values for each. Since Vertica also doesn't have `PIVOT` API nor is it possible to write dynamic SQL there, I'm wondering what is the best way to create a pivot table in Vertica.

Also, because the original/source table has about 180m rows, what would be the most efficient (computationally speaking) way to do the pivoting. I thought about splitting the original table by three or more (grouping by `Geography`, `Period`, `Campaign`, and `VaribleName` and splitting by `Campaign` and `VariableName`) and launching the individual pivotting process within each group before merging them back together. Effectively, I hope to 'parallalize' the pivoting process to speed up the time. Would that help?

Thank you in advanced for your suggestions/advice!

Answer (score 2):

This answer explains how to generate the SQL you need.  After generating the SQL, you need to run it.

First do:

```
select distinct campaign, variable_name
from t;
```

This generates all your code.  Put this in a spreadsheet and use formulas to create the line:

```
(case when campaign = $campaign and variable_name = $variable_name then variable_value else 0 end) as $campaign_$variable_name,
```

You can also do this in SQL as:

```
select distinct 
       replace(replace('(case when campaign = ''$campaign'' and variable_name = ''$variable_name'' then variable_value else 0 end) as $campaign_$variable_name,',
                        '$campaign', campaign
                      ), $variable_name, variable_name
              )
from t;
```

This is most of the SQL you need to write.  Do the following:

- Put `select geography, period,` before the first line
- Remove the final comma
- Add `from t group by geography, period`
- Run the SQL statement

Comment: Thank you. I think you meant to put a single quote around `$variable_name` in the answer above? Running that snippet generates the needed `CASE` statements, but could you elaborate more on how combine that generated `CASE` statements with `SELECT Geography, Period, `? My goal is to launch a VSQL script that is scheduled to run everyday at specific time. Thank you again!

Comment: One more minor note, using `REPLACE` throws this error: Function replace may give a 845008-octet result; the limit is 65000 octets. So via Google-ing, I finally ended up using `REGEXP_REPLACE` to overcome that. Please suggest if there's a better alternative otherwise. Thank you!

Comment: @user1330974 . . . That seems really long.  The result should not be bigger than a hundred or two hundred characters.

Comment: It's because I have so many distinct combination between `Campaign` and `VariableName` columns... That's also why I turned to StackOverflow for sage advice. :) Could you please elaborate more on how I should proceed after generating the case statements using the snippet you've provided? I'm not quite sure if I understand the bullet-ed section of your answer. Thank you!

Comment: What I have got so far is as below:

select distinct 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('(case when Campaign = mycampaign and VariableName = myvariable_name then VariableValue else 0 end) as mycampaign_myvariable_name,',
                        'mycampaign', Campaign
                      ), 'myvariable_name', VariableName
              )
from incampaign_IRT_all_last_60_days

Comment: @user1330974 . . .Distinct combinations wouldn't affect the length of any single `replace()`.  There is no aggregation in this query; each row would be short.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand what you mean and it makes sense. It is because a few of the campaigns have long names. I am now using Python+VSQL to prepare the script because it seems impossible to do it all in Vertica...

Answer (score 0):

create table pivotst 
(
master_country varchar(25)
);
`select  max(decode(rn, 1, master_country, null)) || ', ' ||max(decode(rn, 2, master_country, null)) || ', ' ||max(decode(rn, 3, master_country, null)) || ', ' ||max(decode(rn, 4, master_country, null)) || ', ' ||max(decode(rn, 5, master_country, null)) master_country from (select master_country, row_number() over () rn from pivotst) foo;`
INSERT INTO pivotst values ('Hyderabad');
INSERT INTO pivotst values ('chennai');

select * from pivotst;

select  max(decode(rn, 1, master_country, null)) || ', ' ||max(decode(rn, 2, master_country, null)) || ', ' ||max(decode(rn, 3, master_country, null)) || ', ' ||max(decode(rn, 4, master_country, null)) || ', ' ||max(decode(rn, 5, master_country, null)) master_country from (select master_country, row_number() over () rn from pivotst) foo;

Comment: ouput : chennai,hyderabad,mumbai,bengaluru